Tailwind CSS: Ignore Linebreaks via <br/> on mobile screen
I have the following code:
<h2>
  Where ever you go <br/> i am there.
</h2>

On mobile screens I dont want the <br/> to enforce line break. Any idea how to achieve this using Tailwind CSS?
I tried using multiple code blocks but that feels like repetitive code and hurts SEO.

just use media query and set it to display: none when in mobile

@Eezo thank you will check it out via tailwind classes if it works

You can add class to <br> tag.
In tailwind, <br class="hidden sm:inline" />
https://play.tailwindcss.com/4koqbTma3P

Its better solution to fixed your issue :
<h2 className="sm:whitespace-nowrap">
  Where ever you go <br className="sm:hidden" /> I am there.
</h2>


why do you say this is better?
